# What properties of the pathogens of infectious diseases make recovered individuals susceptible to the disease?

Tags: immunology, pathology, infection

I was wondering what properties of the pathogens of infectious diseases make these diseases more prone to making recovered individuals immediately susceptible to the disease? I was thinking that with Salmonellosis, for example, there are different variants of the Salmonella type of bacteria, but I'm not sure if having more variants of a pathogen necessarily makes it more difficult for the human body to recognize these pathogens.

Comment: gonorrhea is a good example. https://mbio.asm.org/content/2/3/e00095-11